# Django modelform not returning id

Tags: python, django

I've got a simple view:

```
def admin_videos(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        print(request.POST)
    else:
        a = Note.objects.get(pk=1)
        form = NoteForm(instance=a)
        return render(request, 'administration/index.html',{"form":form})
```

and a modelform:

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    authors = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'note': Textarea(attrs={'class': "form-control note", 'rows': 5}),
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'instance' in kwargs:
            self.fields['note'].widget.attrs['data-id'] = kwargs['instance'].id
```

but when I try to update existing instance:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

the id of instance is not in the request.POST
I'd appreciate any suggestions

Comment: According to the docs, the ModelForm excludes any AutoField (id field) from the form by default.  So, you can explicitly add a hidden field to your form to track the id.  But really, you should not need it, since the id is usually part of the URL itself. e.g. notes/1/ should allow a user to edit the record for pk=1.

Comment: Sometimes when I need the instance `id` for some reason in my template, I will add the `a` into the context and then you can just say `{{ a.id }}`. Obviously this is not related to your case, but you can hack it that way if you need to for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, the reason I don't have the id in url is that I.'m updating more instances  at one url(view and update together). I tried to use formsets but I need to save only one instance at a time, eg have multiple forms in the page. Why is django not exposing id if it is in url anyway?thanks

Comment: In that case, I suggest using a regular form instead of a modelform. Then, you can include the id as a hidden form field, and it will be available in request.POST as long as you remember to render the form hidden fields in your template.  You will have to manually save the model instance from the form's cleaned data.

Comment: Thank you @FariaC. Do you think that formset would be usable? Is there a way to save only one form in a formset?

Comment: Yes, a formset can contain only 1 form if that is all you have. Also use instances = formset.save(commit=false) and iterate through your instances to save one at a time. Take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#saving-objects-in-the-formset